# calculate petrol consumed per second and show on web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I want to calculate the petrol consumed per second and show on the website as a footer.

The calculation will be like, petrol consumption increases by 0.13L per second, so for this, I thought to use setInterval for one second and call a function which will calculate the petrol consumption.

Till now I attempted this:

```js
function random_no() {
  var i;
  i = i + 0.13;

  // jQuery('#random_no_container').html(ran); 
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  /// call your function here
  random_no();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random_no_container">
  Hello. Here you can see petrol consumption per second
</div>
```

How can I show the value of I in liters, in the footer?

I am a beginner, please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things you need to do:

1. Your variable should be global (outside the function)- so that value isn't replaced each time you call the function.  You also need to initalize `i` so it has a starting value (`0`).
2. You need to add a new element (here I used `span`) so you know where to put the fuel data.
3. You needed to change the code for the `.html()` to use your variable `i`.

```js
var i = 0;
function random_no() {
  i += 0.13;

  $('#used').html(i); 
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  /// call your function here
  random_no();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random_no_container">
  Hello. Here you can see petrol consumption per second <span id="used"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is pretty slow.  I would instead opt for a more complex solution which uses the current time, so you don't have to calculate the exact refresh rate of the function:

```js
var start_time = new Date().getTime();
function update_consumption() {
  var time_since_start = ((new Date().getTime()) - start_time) / 1000;
  $('#used').html(Math.round(time_since_start * 0.13 * 100) / 100); 
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  update_consumption();
}, 300);
update_consumption();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random_no_container">
  Hello. Here you can see petrol consumption per second <span id="used"></span>
</div>
```

This second solution works a bit differently:

1. It stores a global variable `start`, which represents the time (in miliseconds) since January 1st 1970 when the program starts.
2. It subtracts the time the function is called, and divides by 1000, to get the number of seconds since the program is started (stored as `time_since_start`).
3. Multiply this by the rate (in `L/s`), and then save this to HTML (rounding using `.round()`) beforehand.

This second solution is (in my opinion) better than the first  a) because the total fuel consumed is determined independently of the refresh rate- so you can update at 300ms intervals, and still be accurate.  b) because `setInterval()` is not always accurate.  This way, you use an independent, accurate timer.

Comment: Is this converted in liters?

Comment: @Sid yes- this is in liters.  `0.13 L/s * number of seconds = number of liters`.

Comment: @DerekBrown just a suggestion, DOM manipulation could happen in interval and `random_no` can just calculate and return a new number. Also, you can limit the value to 3 decimal places. So it can be `function random_no(){ i += 0.13; return i.toFixed(3) }`

Comment: yes right I wanted to limit the decimals.. thank you @Rajesh

Comment: Why have we done this   var time_since_start = ((new Date().getTime()) - start_time) / 1000; ?  and I want interval of a second so setInterval time should be 1000 rather than 300. Am I right? @DerekBrown

Comment: @Sid  `((new Date().getTime()) - start_time) ` is the time since the start of the program in miliseconds.  I divide by 1000 to get regular seconds.

Comment: @Sid in the second solution, the speed of updating is independent of the calculated fuel consumption- so this way it can refresh 3 times per second.

Comment: but the value of i differs by 1st code logic and 2nd code logic. @DerekBrown

Comment: @Sid no it doesn't.  Try starting them at the same time (not scientific, but should convince you of the fact).  The first solution updates once per second, whereas the second solution updates every 300ms (smoother).  However, for any given `t` (time since start), the output is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159199/discussion-between-sid-and-derek-brown).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this willl help you :)

```
var i = 10; // Initialize your variable here; I have used 10.
    function random_no() {
      i = i + 0.13;
      document.getElementById("petrol-cons").innerHTML = i; // the span will contain the value of petrol (value of i )
    }

    window.setInterval(function() {
      /// call your function here
      random_no();
    }, 1000);


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Hello. Here you can see petrol consumption per second : 
  <span id="petrol-cons"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Just a question, you are importing jQuery, so why have you used `document.getElementById`? And if you wish to use vanilla JS functions, why have you imported jQuery? Also notice `<>` icon in editor, You can create a snippet using it

Comment: He is beginner , i thought he must know basic javascript and how it works , so that he can move to jQuery :) :)

Comment: Then you should explain what and why are you doing/suggesting any approach. *I hope this willl help you* is not an explanation.